# How to select all polygons within a selected edge perimeter?

Tags: faces, edges, selection-tools, select

Is there an easy way to select all polygons within a selected edge boundary? Selecting each polygon manually would be a pain.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Select ⇾ Select Loops ⇾ Select Loop Inner-Region.

[image]

Comment: +1 awesome! damn how come i never knew this XD i deleted the request, now everyone will know how :)

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For selection to be confined within a perimeter or boundary, Blender needs to know something that distinguishes both sides of the boundaries. Boundaries can include differences in Material, Normal, UV, [Edges marked as Seam or Sharp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html). So you could for example press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> with those edges in your screenshot selected and choose *Mark Seam*. While hovering your mouse in that area you want to select, press <kbd>L</kbd>. And then in the lower left corner where the Operation Popup shows up, change *Selected Link* to *Seam*. And then clear the boundary later with *Clear Seam*.

[image]

Or you could do it the manual way. But don't worry it isn't that tedious since we have the power of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple faces quickly. In *Face Select* mode, You can click a face and click another face while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to select a group of faces part of a face loop. And you can use a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select an entire grid of faces.

[image]

Comment: I just found out there is a feature as Crantisz has pointed out! Select ⇾ Select Loops ⇾ Select Loop Inner-Region.